# Not possible to use server after db = server.use?

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I was doing a very basic test using node.js, latest orientjs and latest OrientDB:

- open server (using port 2424)
- assign db (server.use)
- server.list()

If I do this, the promise at server.list() hangs and the server shows the error "Impossible to read a chunk of length...". But if I just don't assign the db, it works fine. Also, if I call db functions (like db.record.get) instead of server.list(), that works fine too.

Is it the case that you can't call a server function after calling server.use?

On a related point, is there a way to set a network timeout for orientjs? If I try to do any of this and the target server is not reachable, it just hangs on opening the server and/or assigning the database.

Comment: You may want to open a request to implement this on github?

Comment: Hi Eric i've reproduced it. Seems an issue on session management. Can you open an issue on github please?  Thanks

Comment: Already done (by Enrico Risa): https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs/issues/279